# Transfering data from a .csv to and struct array and then sorting it to save it on a different file

Tags: arrays, c, csv, struct

The code I've written so far goes as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define P  200


typedef struct Point{
    char name[50],  surname[50], email[50];
    int donation;
} Point;


char SortMenu(void);
void PrintArray(Point A[]);
void CopyArray(Point Source[], Point Copy[]);

void BubbleSort(Point A[]);
void ShellSort(long int A[]);
void QuickSort(long int A[], int bottom, int top);
void InsertionSort(long int A[]);
void SelectionSort(long int A[]);
void MergeSort(long int A[], int l, int r);
void Merge(long int A[], int l, int m, int r);

//Global variables
clock_t start, end;

Point points[200];
Point copypoints[200];
Point temp;

int main(){

    //Variable declaration area
    int input, i, give;
    char choice = ' ', choise2 = ' ';
    int array_size;

    //File to store the execution time
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    //CSV file with the data to sort
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen("DonationData.csv", "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    char buffer[200];
    fgets(buffer, 200, file);

    Point points[200] = {};
    Point copypoints[200] = {}; //making another array so that we can check if the sorting was done correctly
    i = 0;
    while(!feof(file)){
        Point* p = points + i;
        sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s %d", &p->name, &p->surname, &p->email, &p->donation);

        fgets(buffer, 200, file);
        i++;
    }

    //printf("Read point: %s %s %s %d", points[i].name, points[i].surname, points[i].email, points[i].donation);
    //PrintArray(copypoints);


    int n = i;
    for(i = 0; i < P; i++){
        printf("Read point: %s %s %s %d\n", points[i].name, points[i].surname, points[i].email, points[i].donation);
    }
    /*
    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < P; i++){
        printf("Read point: %s %s %s %d\n", copypoints[i].name, copypoints[i].surname, copypoints[i].email, copypoints[i].donation);
    }
    */

    //seed for rand
    srand(time(NULL));



        do{

        //Calling user Menu
        choice = SortMenu();
        if (choice == 'Q'){
            break;
        }

        //printf("%d", input);
        //system("pause");




        //calling all the functions  (I used if statements because at the start switch was not working but now I know why)
        if ( choice == '1' ){
            CopyArray(points, copypoints);
            printf("Sorting your Data using Bubble-sort.\n");
            BubbleSort(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n Finished Sorting!\n\n");
            printf("Before: ");
            PrintArray(points);
            printf("\nAfter: ");
            PrintArray(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n");
            double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            //fprintf(fp, "Bubble-sort = Execution time: %lf | Scenario %d\n",time_taken,s+1);

            printf("Essential info has been recorded to the text file.\n");
            //system("pause");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if ( choice == '2' ){
            CopyArray(points, copypoints);
            printf("Sorting your Data using Quick-sort.\n");
            QuickSort(copypoints, 0, P-1);
            printf("\n\n Finished Sorting!\n\n");
            printf("Before: ");
            PrintArray(points);
            printf("\nAfter: ");
            PrintArray(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n");
            double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            fprintf(fp, "Quick-sort = Execution time: %lf | Scenario %d\n",time_taken,s+1);

            printf("Essential info has been recorded to the text file.\n");
            //system("pause");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if ( choice == '3' ){
            CopyArray(points, copypoints);
            printf("Sorting your Data using Merge-sort.\n");
            MergeSort(copypoints, 0, scenarios[s] - 1);
            printf("\n\n Finished Sorting!\n\n");
            printf("Before: ");
            PrintArray(points);
            printf("\nAfter: ");
            PrintArray(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n");
            double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            fprintf(fp, "Merge-sort = Execution time: %lf | Scenario %d\n",time_taken,s+1);

            printf("Essential info has been recorded to the text file.\n");
            //system("pause");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if ( choice == '4' ){
            CopyArray(points, copypoints);
            printf("Sorting your Data using Selection-sort.\n");
            SelectionSort(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n Finished Sorting!\n\n");
            printf("Before: ");
            PrintArray(points);
            printf("\nAfter: ");
            PrintArray(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n");
            double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            fprintf(fp, "Selectio-sort = Execution time: %lf | Scenario %d\n",time_taken,s+1);

            printf("Essential info has been recorded to the text file.\n");
            //system("pause");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if ( choice == '5' ){
            CopyArray(points, copypoints);
            printf("Sorting your Data using Insertion-sort.\n");
            InsertionSort(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n Finished Sorting!\n\n");
            printf("Before: ");
            PrintArray(points);
            printf("\nAfter: ");
            PrintArray(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n");
            double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            fprintf(fp, "Insertion-sort = Execution time: %lf | Scenario %d\n",time_taken,s+1);

            printf("Essential info has been recorded to the text file.\n");
            //system("pause");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if ( choice == '6' ){
            CopyArray(points, copypoints);
            printf("Sorting your Data using Shell-sort.\n");
            ShellSort(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n Finished Sorting!\n\n");
            printf("Before: ");
            PrintArray(points);
            printf("\nAfter: ");
            PrintArray(copypoints);
            printf("\n\n");
            double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            fprintf(fp, "Shell-sort = Execution time: %lf | Scenario %d\n",time_taken,s+1);

            printf("Essential info has been recorded to the text file.\n");
            //system("pause");
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if ( choice == '7' ){
            printf("Printing your Array...\n");
            PrintArray(array, P);
        }
        else if ( choice == 'E' ){
            printf("Exiting Scenario.\n\n\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("\n\n Please enter 1-7 or E!\n\n");
        }


        //Change scenario question so you can record all the scenarios in a row
        if (s == 9 && choice != 'E'){
            printf("\nYou're on Scenario 10. Would you like to change the scenario?\n 1. YES\n 2. NO\n");
            printf("Choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &input);

            if(input == 1){
                printf("Change to scenario:");
                scanf("%d", &input);
                s = input -2;
                printf("\n\n");
                break;
            }

            printf("\n\n");
        }
        


    }while( choice != 'E'  );


    fclose(fp);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

//I stole this because mine just wouldn't work
char SortMenu() {
    char ch1 = ' ';
    char ch2[] = {' ', ' ', ' '};

    // system("clear");  // For DOS-based system("cls");

    printf("\n\n");
    //Menu for the users
    printf("Please sellect what sorting system you would like to use.\n"
           "1. Bubble-sort\n"
           "2. Quick-sort\n"
           "3. Merge-sort\n"
           "4. Selection-sort\n"
           "5. Insertion sort\n"
           "6. Shell sort\n"
           "7. Print Array\n"
           "E. Exit current scenario\n"
           "Q. Quit Program\n");
    printf("Choice: ");

    scanf("%s", ch2);
    ch1 = ch2[0];

    return ch1;
}




void PrintArray(Point A[]) {
    long int i;
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i=0; i < P; i++) {
        printf("Read point: %s %s %s %d\n", A[i].name, A[i].surname, A[i].email, A[i].donation);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    //system("pause");
}



void CopyArray(Point Source[], Point Copy[]) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i < P; i++)
        Copy[i] = Source[i];
}


void swap(Point* A, Point* B ) {
    Point temp = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = temp;
}


double power(int base, int exponent) {
    double result;
    int i;

    result = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= exponent; i++)
        result = result * base;

    return result;
}


void BubbleSort(Point A[]) {
    start = clock();
    int j, last, t;
    Point temp;

    last = 1;
    do {
        t = 0;
        for (j = (P-1); j >= last; j--) {
            if (A[j-1].donation > A[j].donation) {
                swap(&A[j-1], &A[j]);
                t = j;
            }
        }
        last = t;
    } while (t > 0);
    end = clock();
}


void QuickSort(long int A[], int bottom, int top) {
    start = clock();
    int i, j, x, k;

    i = bottom;
    j = top;
    k = (bottom + top) / 2;
    x = A[k];

    do {
        while (A[i] < x)
            i++;
        while (A[j] > x)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(&A[i], &A[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (bottom < j)
        QuickSort(A, bottom, j);
    if (i < top)
        QuickSort(A, i, top);

    end = clock();
}


void SelectionSort(long int A[]) {
    start =  clock();
    int i, j, x, k;

    for (i=(P-1); i >= 1; i--) {
        x = A[i];
        k = i;
        for (j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (A[j] > x) {
                k = j;
                x = A[j];
            }
        }
        swap(&A[i], &A[k]);
    }
    end = clock();
}



void InsertionSort(long int A[]) {
    start = clock();
    int i, j, t;

    for (j=1; j < P; j++) {
        i = j - 1;
        t = A[j];
        do {
            if (t >= A[i])
                break;
            A[i+1] = A[i];
            i--;
        } while (i >= 0);
        A[i+1] = t;
    }
    end = clock();
}



void ShellSort(long int A[]) {
    start = clock();
    int i, j, s, pas, qq;
    double h[20];

    for (i=0; i <= 19; i++)
        h[i] = power(2, i);

    for (s=19; s >= 0; s--) {
        pas = h[s];
        for (j = pas; j < P; j++) {
            i = j - pas;
            qq = A[j];
            do {
                if (qq >= A[i])
                    break;
                A[i+pas] = A[i];
                i = i - pas;
            } while (i >= 0);
            A[i+pas] = qq;
        }
    }
    end = clock();
}



void MergeSort(long int A[], int l, int r)
{
    start = clock();
    if (l < r) {

        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        MergeSort(A, l, m);
        MergeSort(A, m + 1, r);

        Merge(A, l, m, r);
    }
    end = clock();
}

void Merge(long int A[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;


    int L[n1], R[n2];


    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = A[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = A[m + 1 + j];


    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            A[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            A[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }


    while (i < n1) {
        A[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }


    while (j < n2) {
        A[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

I have this assignment for University where I have to take data out of a .csv and then sort it with 6 different sorting algorithms and measure the execution time.

The problems that I've encountered and I'm stuck at are the following:

1.When I transfer all the data to a struct array at the end of every row there's an awkard 0 (look at the screenshots bellow)

2.I've tried passing the array from bubblesort fuction to swap function but it doesn't swap them (I think it might be because of the previous problem)

**The .csv looks like this, a row has a name, surname, email, and an intiger**

```
"Eric","Tucker","e.tucker@randatmail.com",4591
"Catherine","Hawkins","c.hawkins@randatmail.com",9325
"Bruce","Harper","b.harper@randatmail.com",8371
"Kristian","Bailey","k.bailey@randatmail.com",437
"Garry","Harrison","g.harrison@randatmail.com",976
"Rafael","Farrell","r.farrell@randatmail.com",8685
"Penelope","Craig","p.craig@randatmail.com",1224
```

**This is the output of the first problem I was talking about**

```
Read point: "Rafael","Phillips","r.phillips@randatmail.com",7092 92  0
Read point: "Lucia","Carroll","l.carroll@randatmail.com",6879   0
Read point: "Lyndon","Roberts","l.roberts@randatmail.com",6460   0
```

> If you need more info from me, let me know and I'll provide it to you

Comment: `sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s %d"` How does that deal with the commas? It doesn't seem to at all. `%s` will match any non-whitespace character. So based on your file format which has no spaces the first `%s` should match the whole line. Always check the return value of `sscanf`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget the ***minimal*** part of your [mcve].

Comment: As a hint: The `scanf` format `%s` reads *space delimited* strings. You don't parse the actual input in the correct way.

Comment: You also have many other problems, like possibly going beyond the end of the initialized part of your arrays (you always iterate over `P` elements, no matter how many were actually read from the file).